# Thymeleaf throws 404 on URL it has already successfully connected to? Is this binding correctly?

Tags: java, forms, controller, thymeleaf

I'm converting a project to Thymeleaf and it's doing some strange stuff. I have my controller here:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/articles")
public class ArticleController {

    private ArticleRepo articleRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ArticleController(ArticleRepo articleRepo) {
        this.articleRepo = articleRepo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Article> findall() {
        return articleRepo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/addArticle")
    public String getAddArticle(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("article", new Article());
        return "submitAnArticle";
    }

    @PostMapping("/addArticle")
    public String submitAddArticle(@ModelAttribute Article newArticle) {
        articleRepo.save(newArticle);
        return "submitAnArticle";
    }

}
```

And my submitAnArticle.html file here:

```html
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/articles/addArticle}" th:object="${article}" method="post">
 <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{authors}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{genre}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{date}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
```

The thing is, whenever I fill out the information and hit submit, I get a 404 error. What gives?

Note: I've even tried mapping it to a different HTML file (result.html) and it throws the same error as shown below:

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

The thing is that it's loading the "submitAnArticle" endpoint (by displaying submitAnArticle.html), but it throws a 404 when it's submitted.

I'm losing my mind over this. If someone can help me I'd appreciate it. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Debug to see if your save method `articleRepo.save(newArticle);` is working.

Comment: Great suggestion, but I already know this method is working since it successfully stores data in the database via postman. 

It's this whole Thymeleaf thing is confusing to me because I'm new to it. Maybe I'm not understanding it, but it doesn't seem to make anything easier. It's just taking something that can already be done through existing tools and demanding a unique syntax or standards for it (all of which I'm struggling with). Even the documentation I've been looking at from their website has not been super helpful - hence I am here.

Comment: What do you mean by this `The thing is that it's loading the "submitAnArticle" endpoint (by displaying submitAnArticle.html)`? How are you loading the `submitAnArticle.html`? What is the url?

Comment: And Thymeleaf is good. You will see. There is a reason why Spring recommeds Thymeleaf instead of jsps.

Comment: What I mean is that, whenever you hit the "/addArticle" endpoint, the string "submitAnArticle" returned to the user within that controller's endpoint actually serves up a page called submitAnArticle.html that I have saved in src/main/resources/templates/ (or at least, that's how I understand it).

I wound up trying to returning a "result.html" on the PostMapping version of ("/addArticle") endpoint, but that gives the same error. 


I'm also very confused how the GetMapping version of the endpoint passes in a model (model Model) when it's a get request.@AbdullahKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the object needed to have it's datatypes changed to Strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not import necessary jar, put these in pom.xml or download by yourself

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```